# Azure Devops Pipelines integration with Bitbucket not showing users who triggered builds

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-pipelines

I setup an Azure CI/CD to build my project from a Bitbucket location with a `YAML` pipeline

However whenever I push to my branch that is included in the `trigger` branches, Azure Pipelines keeps saying that it's been triggered by:

[image]

If I wanted to make change using the web UI editor and push, it will show to run under my username.

How can make all triggers to look under usernames?

Comment: How did you setup the Azure CI/CD to build from a Bitbucket repo. I  failed to reproduce above scenario. I created a bitbucket service connection on my azure devops project, and select the bitbucket service connection as the pipeline source. And  the Azure Pipelines showed triggered under my Bitbucket account username

Comment: I have created a new Azure Pipelines from the Azure Devops GUI and selected "Existing YAML file" pointing it to my `azure-pipelines.yaml` file in the Bitbucket repo

Comment: How is the bitbucket connected to your azure devops project? Using service connection? Could you try delete the old service connection and create a new one.

Comment: Its not entirely visible in how its connected, there is service connection Service connection of type Bitbucket Cloud using grant authorization, but on Execution History there are no entries at all

Comment: I removed the service connection and I get an auth error, it says that the repo does not exist, recreating the service connection and retrying presists with "Triggered By Microsoft..."

Comment: Can you try to recreate the service connection using `Basic Authentication`, use your username and password for bitbucket account.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT if I do that, wouldn't it show my username all the time? so if another developer pushed, would it show under their username or mine?

Comment: If the bitbucket service connection was first created using `grant authorization`, you will be prompted a window for username and password too. I think it depends on the login account of bitbucket server. I checked the webhook of my bitbucket account and found azure devops pipeline actually take the trigger infomation from the request body the webhook of bitbucket. You can go to your bitbucket repository settings-->webhooks-->click view requests of the webhook to azure devops pipeline-->(enable history if not enabled)-->click view details of the previous event-->Show request body.

Comment: Hi Did your tried using your username and password? How did it go?

Comment: I did - I tried both `grant` and `basic` auth(username/pass), it still shows the `Microsoft` trigger. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: I had a bunch of repositories triggering the build pipeline from my "Development" branch in Bitbucket, which has been working for a long time. I noticed today stopped working. Maybe is a problem related to Azure Devops?